# Not able to load relative path URL in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, header, android-webview, relative-path

I have a remote URL and I want to load it in my web view. This page is secured by headers. The page is getting loaded but it is not loading the relative URLS which is inside the HTML I am trying to load.

The same URL is perfectly working on web but failing to load here. The main problem is it is not loading the java script files.

Here is my code:

```
    WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webViewSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webViewSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webViewSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webViewSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    webViewSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webViewSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webViewSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webViewSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);


    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Toast.makeText(Report.this,"Finished loading",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }




        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(flip_book);


                httpGet.setHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + preferencesHelper.getPref("JSESSIONID") + "; X-CSRF-TOKEN=" + preferencesHelper.getPref(preferencesHelper.csrftoken));
                httpGet.setHeader("JSESSIONID", preferencesHelper.getPref("JSESSIONID"));
                httpGet.setHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", URLEncoder.encode(preferencesHelper.getPref(preferencesHelper.csrftoken), "UTF-8"));

                HttpResponse httpReponse = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream responseInputStream = httpReponse.getEntity().getContent();

                return new WebResourceResponse("text/html", "charset=UTF-8", responseInputStream);

                //text/html

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                //return null to tell WebView we failed to fetch it WebView should try again.
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //return null to tell WebView we failed to fetch it WebView should try again.
                return null;
            }
        }


    });

    webView.loadData("<iframe src=\"" +
                    "" +
                    flip_book +
                    "\"></iframe>", "text/html",
            "utf-8");
```

Please help.

Comment: I am not getting that relative url part. Can you please explain it proper? @Ruhani

Comment: @PratikDasa http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: So that relative path urls are not loading? Is this the problem right? @Ruhani

Comment: Check my answer and try with it, maybe it should work. @Ruhani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try it with OkHTTP something like this:

```
loader.showLoader();

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {



        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            loader.dismissLoader();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            loader.dismissLoader();
            showAlert("Something went wrong","Ok");
        }

        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

            try {

                String url = request.getUrl().toString();

                return getNewResponse(url);

            }  catch (Exception e) {
                //return null to tell WebView we failed to fetch it WebView should try again.
                return null;
            }
        }


        private WebResourceResponse getNewResponse(String url) {

            try {
                OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url.trim())
                        .addHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + preferencesHelper.getPref("JSESSIONID") + "; X-CSRF-TOKEN=" + preferencesHelper.getPref(preferencesHelper.csrftoken))
                        .addHeader("JSESSIONID", preferencesHelper.getPref("JSESSIONID"))
                        .addHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", URLEncoder.encode(preferencesHelper.getPref(preferencesHelper.csrftoken), "UTF-8")).build();

                Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

                return new WebResourceResponse(
                        null,
                        response.header("content-encoding", "utf-8"),
                        response.body().byteStream()
                );

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

        }




    });



    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);


    webView.loadUrl(flip_book);
```

Comment: Works!! Thank you Adish!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code, may be it should work:

```
WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webViewSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webViewSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webViewSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webViewSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    webViewSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webViewSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webViewSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webViewSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);


    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Toast.makeText(Report.this,"Finished loading",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }




        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(flip_book);


                httpGet.setHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + preferencesHelper.getPref("JSESSIONID") + "; X-CSRF-TOKEN=" + preferencesHelper.getPref(preferencesHelper.csrftoken));
                httpGet.setHeader("JSESSIONID", preferencesHelper.getPref("JSESSIONID"));
                httpGet.setHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", URLEncoder.encode(preferencesHelper.getPref(preferencesHelper.csrftoken), "UTF-8"));

                HttpResponse httpReponse = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream responseInputStream = httpReponse.getEntity().getContent();

                return new WebResourceResponse("text/html", "charset=UTF-8", responseInputStream);

                //text/html

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                //return null to tell WebView we failed to fetch it WebView should try again.
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //return null to tell WebView we failed to fetch it WebView should try again.
                return null;
            }
        }


    });

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("<iframe src=\"" +
                    "" +
                    flip_book +
                    "\"></iframe>", "text/html",
            "utf-8",null);
```

Comment: May I know the changes you made here?

Comment: webView.loadDataWithBaseURL this method is changed. @RuhaniChoudhary

Comment: Thanks @Pratik but that doesnt works. The syntax is also not correct.

Comment: Check my edited answer, loadDataWithBaseUrl needs 5 parameters. Sorry it was my mistake. @RuhaniChoudhary

Comment: Sorry Pratik, again syntax error and this doesnt works. I tried this too.

Comment: Which syntax error is coming? Can you tell me? Or have you solved that syntax error? @RuhaniChoudhary

Comment: Okay, no worries lets find another solution. @RuhaniChoudhary

Comment: Thanks Pratik for helping. :)

Comment: Looks like you are new comer in android? @RuhaniChoudhary

Comment: Yes, can you please help this new bee? :)

Comment: Haha of course, lets start research and find out the solution. @RuhaniChoudhary

Comment: I think new bee solved this problem with her own? @RuhaniChoudhary